# Ajax Call Custom Model Binder returning FormData in URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, model-binding

I have created a custom Model Binder for a complex collection that I am posting to via Ajax.  All is well and good, until i return the JsonResult to the page, then entire FormData is appended to the URL. Is there something small i am missing here?

I have some ajax to post the form.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#SaveButton").click(function(e) {
    var form = $("#myForm");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/myController/SaveAll',
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        error: function(xhr) {
            console.log('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
        },
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        async: true
    });
});
```

});

The controller action.

```
      public JsonResult SaveAll([ModelBinder(typeof(CustomModelBinder))]ProvinceListViewModel model)
    {
           // process something
            return this.Json(new
            {
                Sucess = true
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Here is my custom model binder that use the request.FormData

```
 public class CustomModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    private NameValueCollection _formCollection;

    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(ProvinceViewModel))
            {
                HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;

                // set the form collection 
                this._formCollection = request.Form;


                // build the view models, parse form collection


                // return the tab container view model
                return new ProvinceViewModel();



            }
            else
            {
                return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
            }
        }
 }
```

The result url has the form data appended to it. How do i prevent this? Thanks in advance.
        _RequestVerificationToken=PK4YYR1fTh15rpHQwE883NlVOLho7LLWL7cdH_3jP0lq8SXhKGvOHq7imuBUf-xr6sOP5dIMbVMPVcPuA1Rsgt616x3Tub4DK57VCGZ4-oo1&MyId=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying your post like this:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/myController/SaveAll',
        data: {'Data':form.serialize()},
        dataType: "json",
        error: function(xhr) {
            console.log('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
        },
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        async: true
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this with no change. The form data is still returned to URL after POST.

Comment: @mflair2000  is the button your #SaveButton a "button" ?

Comment: Jesus. Thank you, that is what it was. I have been spending far too long on server side coding here.

Comment: You could probably add e.PreventDefault() to stop the page from jumping on the submit too.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was i had a submit button in the form and was attach the onclick event to it. I change it to a div element and the problem was resolved.